# Using pandas/numpy how to write a dynamic code for next analysis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Data :**

```
   District      Crop      Village  Area
0     Nagar  Soyabean        Aagar    10
1     Nagar  Soyabean    Dhagewadi    32
2     Nagar  Soyabean    Sherewadi    34
3     Nagar  Soyabean     Shindwad    42
4     Nagar  Soyabean  Ambikanagar    45
5     Nagar  Soyabean     Khanapur    65
6     Nagar  Soyabean      Dhokari    84
7     Nagar  Soyabean       Pangri   105
8     Nagar  Soyabean     Pi.Khand   120
9     Nagar  Soyabean     Gardhani   122
10    Nagar  Soyabean       Takali   127
11    Nagar    Cotton        Aagar   125
12    Nagar    Cotton    Dhagewadi   110
13    Nagar    Cotton    Sherewadi   153
14    Nagar    Cotton     Shindwad   147
15    Nagar    Cotton  Ambikanagar   180
16    Nagar    Cotton     Khanapur   185
17    Nagar    Cotton      Dhokari   100
18    Nagar    Cotton       Pangri   135
19    Nagar    Cotton     Pi.Khand   120
20    Nagar    Cotton     Gardhani   174
21    Nagar    Cotton       Takali    85
```

**Python Code :**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv("/home/desktop/Data.csv")
df
df1=df[1:11]  #Using df1 for getting soyabean Crop area 
df2=df[12:22] #Using df2 for getting Cotton Crop area
df1 = df1.sort('Area', ascending=False)  # getting villages in descending order for select top 5 villages for soyabean crop
df2 = df2.sort('Area', ascending=False) # getting villages in descending order for select top 5 villages for cotton crop
```

The data is sample file, but i have 25 different Crops data.

So, in my code i am using df1, df2....df25 for 25 crops.

and i need to check total row  for each crop .

and there is chance to type wrong numbers.

like
df2 = df[12:22] , 
if sometime typo  df2=df[13:22] then it will wrong selection in descending order.

So, I need to some logic code which will apply easy for "Crop" Column.

If crop = soyabean,  then it will automatically display top villages(descending order) for 
soyabean crops by using area .

If crop = cotton , then it will automatically display top villages for cotton crop .

No need to type df2= df[12:22] for cotton crop.

Any helps?
Thanks.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're asking. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do and provide sample output?

Comment: @Andrew, for example : I have 3000  rows, and "Paddy crop" comes in row 2975 to 3000 , then i have write my code  df25=df[2975:3000] . and i am each time looking in rows numbers for fetch data for different crops. is there any other way to get data from "Crop" column,  for find out villages in descending order ?

Comment: Do you need to create new dataframes for each crop?

Comment: @AndrewL , yes exactly,

Comment: @AndrewL , I want some loop and get data from automatically, if crop= paddy then it will show me  data only where my row 2975 to row 3000  for paddy crop

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called boolean indexing and is done with the following syntax:

```
df_0 = df[df['Crop'] == 'Soyabean']
df_1 = df[df['Crop'] == 'Cotton']

df_0
   District      Crop      Village  Area
0     Nagar  Soyabean        Aagar    10
1     Nagar  Soyabean    Dhagewadi    32
2     Nagar  Soyabean    Sherewadi    34
3     Nagar  Soyabean     Shindwad    42
4     Nagar  Soyabean  Ambikanagar    45
5     Nagar  Soyabean     Khanapur    65
6     Nagar  Soyabean      Dhokari    84
7     Nagar  Soyabean       Pangri   105
8     Nagar  Soyabean     Pi.Khand   120
9     Nagar  Soyabean     Gardhani   122
10    Nagar  Soyabean       Takali   127
```

This does not require a loop. You can read more on this here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: @AndrwL  perfect.! Thanks for save my time to looking in rows :)

Comment: @Kiran Happy to help